# How would you store these user schedules in a database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am building a system where a user will have to select a block of time as `available` and then another user `reserves` that time. Each event is a set time of 20 minutes and I want the person being reserved to lay out hourly blocks of `available` time at once on different days in a calendar.

I am having trouble deciding how to represent this simply in the database, my current idea is to have an `available` table be a FK to the user. When they select a block of `X` hours from `TIME A` to `TIME B`, it would create `X * 3` rows in the database for available 20 minute `slots`.

When a user `reserves` one of those slots, the available row is deleted and another `reservation` row is created which has a FK to two different users.

Is there a simpler way to represent this? It seems like it would be creating an awful lot of unnecessary rows in the db...

Comment: Why not just have flags to mark slots as "available" and "reserved"?  That will save the "delete and create" step around reserving a slot.  But you're going to have a lot of rows, and that's not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: yeah that is better, just wanted to run it by someone to see if there wasn't a simpler overall method. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to store it?  Simple way to check/assign reservations?  Neither is easy; both gets messy.

Here's another way.

A `BIGINT UNSIGNED` can hold 64 bits, one for each 20-minute slot for 21 hours of a day.  (This won't work if you need the to span all 24 hours.)

Operators `&` and `|` and `<<` can be used for building reservation blocks, checking them, etc.

```
(1 << 14) - (1 << 9)
```

will have 6 consecutive bits turned on -- to represent 2 hours.  It is hex `3F00` -- see `SELECT (1 << 14) - (1 << 8);`.

```
(this & that) != 0  -- check for any overlap
```

etc.